# How to pass img src as a parameter in a stateless function in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parameters, next.js

I want to pass img src as a parameter in a stateless function in next js.
This is my component file:

```
  import styles from "../../styles/modules/Card.module.css"
  import Image from "next/image"
    
    const Activity = (img) => {
     
      return ( <>
          <div className={styles.card} id="blue">
           <Image className={styles.card_img} src={img} width={160} height={360} />
          </div>
    
      </> );
    }
     
    export default Activity;
```

Also the file from where it is being called:

```
import Activity from "../../components/Lists/Activity"
  
const About = () => {
  return ( <>    
    <Activity img="https://placekitten.com/289/220"/>
    </>);
}
 
export default About;
```

This is the error I get while running:

**Server Error**
TypeError: src.startsWith is not a function

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img` is not *string* in your case. It is an *object* with a property `img` on it. So it looks like this: `img.img`. You can pass it like this:

```
<Image className={styles.card_img} src={img.img} width={160} height={360} />
```